# NodeJS + NextJS 13 - ERROR Could not resolve dependency:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I just went and upgraded all our apps dependencies, and have been greeted with warnings like:

```
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0" from react-sizeme@2.6.12
npm WARN node_modules/react-stack-grid/node_modules/react-sizeme
npm WARN   react-sizeme@"^2.2.0" from react-stack-grid@0.7.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-stack-grid
```

I know I have not installed `react-stack-grid` nor `react-sizeme` However these are saying that they are installed. How do I fix this issue?

My package.json dependencies are:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^35.3.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^6.7.0",
    "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter": "^1.1.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "get-audio-duration": "^3.1.1",
    "get-blob-duration": "^1.2.0",
    "got": "^12.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mongodb": "^4.11.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "music-metadata": "^8.1.0",
    "next": "^13.0.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.15.1",
    "next-connect": "^0.13.0",
    "node-id3": "^0.2.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-tweet-embed": "^2.0.0",
    "react-youtube": "^10.0.0",
    "sharethis-reactjs": "^1.6.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "string-strip-html": "^11.6.20",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.0.2"
  }
```

I ran `npm audit fix --force` and got this result.

```
npm audit report

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service in enclosure regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
No fix available
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
    watchpack-chokidar2  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
      watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
      Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
      node_modules/watchpack
        webpack  1.12.3 - 5.0.0-rc.6
        Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
        Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
        Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack
        node_modules/webpack
          css-loader  0.6.0 - 3.6.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of icss-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-extract-imports
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-local-by-default
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-scope
          Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-values
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/css-loader
            @zeit/next-css  *
            Depends on vulnerable versions of css-loader
            Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
            Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-loader
            node_modules/@zeit/next-css
          mini-css-extract-plugin  <=0.12.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
          terser-webpack-plugin  <=2.2.1
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin

loader-utils  <2.0.3
Severity: critical
Prototype pollution in webpack loader-utils - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-76p3-8jx3-jpfq
No fix available
node_modules/loader-utils
  postcss-loader  <=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of loader-utils
  node_modules/postcss-loader

lodash  <=4.17.20
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-jf85-cpcp-j695
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x5rq-j2xg-h7qm
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p6mc-m468-83gw
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4xc9-xhrj-v574
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fvqr-27wr-82fm
Command Injection in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35jh-r3h4-6jhm
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-29mw-wpgm-hmr9
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-quill@2.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/lodash
  quilljs  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  node_modules/quilljs
    react-quill  <=0.0.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of quilljs
    node_modules/react-quill

postcss  <7.0.36
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5
No fix available
node_modules/postcss
  icss-utils  <=3.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/icss-utils
  postcss-modules-extract-imports  <=1.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports
  postcss-modules-local-by-default  <=1.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default
  postcss-modules-scope  <=1.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-scope
  postcss-modules-values  <=1.3.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-modules-values

20 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 4 high, 8 critical)
```

Comment: Which npm and Node versions are you using? What platform are you running on (Windows/Linux/etc.)?

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz was running Node V 16.15.1 and NPM v 8.11.0 and on Mac (but will be using docker on ubuntu for production)